# How does this Python Lambda recursion expression work?

Tags: python, recursion, lambda

```
rec_fn = lambda: 10==11 or rec_fn()
rec_fn()
```

I am new to Python and trying to understand how lambda expressions work. Can somebody explain how this recursion is working? I am able to understand that 10==11 will be 'false' and that's how rec_fn will be called again and again recursively.

But what I am not able to get is this seemingly new way of writing a lambda expression.

whatever happened to `lambda x: x+y` where there is a parameter 'x' going into the unnamed function?

Also, why is

```
rec_fn() = lambda: .... // a syntax error
rec_fn = lambda: .... //syntactically correct - WHY?
```

What is rec_fn? Is it a function or a variable?

Comment: Thanks everybody! You explanations are tremendous :D But before I accept the answer, I need to know what is happening inside the lambda. How is the conditional construct "or" working? It's somewhat like a if/else statement. "If not this, then execute that" kind of a thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may help to think of a function call as an *operator.* Because that's what it is. When you do `rec_fn()` you are doing two things. First, you're getting a reference to the object named `rec_fn`. This happens to be a function, but that doesn't matter (in Python, objects besides functions are callable). Then there is `()` which means "call the object I just named." It is possible to get a reference to a function without calling it, just by leaving off the parentheses, and then you can assign it different names, any of which can then be used to call it by *adding* the parentheses.

```
def func1():
   print "func1"

func2 = func1

func2()       # prints "func1"
```

Now you can see how the lambda works.

```
func3 = lambda x: x+1
```

You are doing the same as the `func2 = func1` line above, except the lambda expression *is* the function. The syntax is just different; the lambda function can be defined without giving it a name.

Lambdas can have any number of parameters, so `lambda: 3` is a function that takes no parameters and always returns 3, while `lambda x, y: x+y` is a function that takes two parameters and returns their sum.

As to the way `or` is being used, it's taking advantage of *short-circuiting.* Basically, `or` knows that if its first operand is `True`, it doesn't need to evaluate the second, because the result is going to be `True` regardless of what the second argument is. You could thus read this as `if not 10==11: rec_fn()`. By the way, `and` also short-circuits, although it does so if the first argument is `False` since it knows that the result will be `False` regardless of what the second argument is.

Answer (score 0):

A function invocation -- `x()` -- is an expression. It is lot a legal syntax construct on the left side of an assignment. What should happen? (It is roughly the same as saying `42 = lambda: ....`)

In the 2nd case, you are simply assigning the new function object created (with the `lambda` keyword) to a variable (named `rec_fn`) and not invoking a function.

Perhaps a more clear way is to use the (preferred) non-lambda nested function approach:

```
# just for example, not really useful as it is unless you like to eat CPU
def rec_fn():
  return 10 == 11 or rec_fn()

rec_fn()
```

The `lambda` keyword is just a syntactic shortcut which can be used as part of an expression.

`rec_fn` is a *local variable* in the above cases (assuming said code is nested in a function/method). The `rec_fn` variable *stores a function object* which can later be invoked with `()`. Methods are roughly the same (functions which can be invoked), but they are *properties* and not *variables*.

Answer (score 0):

```
  rec_fn = lambda: 10==11 or rec_fn()
  rec_fn()
```

is the similar to this expression, however this one requires a parameter,

```
rec_fn = lambda x: 10==11 or rec_fn(x)
x = ...
rec_fn(x)
```

whereas you'r rec_fn() with you're calling a function with no parameters hence no x

```
rec_fn() = lambda: .... // a syntax error
```

This is trying to set result of the function call rec_fn() (a right had side expression) to a value. There is no variabele there to assign the lambda function to.

```
rec_fn = lambda: .... //syntactically correct - WHY?
```

here rec_fn in the variable that holds the lambda (in essence like a function pointer)

Answer (score 0):

```
rec_fn = lambda: 10==11 or rec_fn()
rec_fn()
```

The body of a function is not evaluated until it is executed.  At the start, `rec_fn` has no value.  The contents of the lambda is just some expression that has some function call on some variable `rec_fn`.  It won't fail yet because the function isn't executed yet.  The new lambda function is then assigned to the variable `rec_fn` followed by a call to the function.  Now since the function is being executed, it will go through the motions up to the function call.  The expression is `10==11 or rec_fn()`.  It's an `or` expresison so the left hand side is evaluated.  `10==11` is False so it must evaluate the right hand side which is a function call to some function (or other callable object) `rec_fn`.  At that point, `rec_fn` is assigned to the function we just created (itself) so it gets called (recursively).  And so on.  It is equivalent to:

```
def rec_fn():
    return 10==11 or rec_fn()
```

Lambdas can be written using as many parameters as necessary.  In the case of `lambda: ...`, there are none specified so it's a "function that takes no arguments."

Just remember, functions (and by extension, lambdas) are first class objects.  You can pass them around like any other object and store them into other variables.

```
rec_fn = lambda: ...
```

is fine because you've defined a lambda function and stored it into the variable `rec_fn`.  It can be called by using that name `rec_fn()` like you would any other function.

```
rec_fn() = lambda: ...
```

on the other hand fails because you cannot assign anything to the result of the function call `rec_fn()`.

Defining a function this way is much different than a normal function definition:

```
def rec_fn2(): # here you may use the parens with the name to indicate it takes no arguments
    ...        # unlike in the lambda assignment above
```

Just try to remember the difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe more understandable example of recursion, factorial lambda version:

```
fact = lambda x: 1 if x == 0 else x*fact(x-1)
prin(fact(10))
```

Output:

```
3628800
```

Be aware of Python's recursion limit, though.

Example of using or as this if..else:

```
print 1 or 'a'
print 'a' or False
print False or True or 0/9
fact_or = lambda x: x == 0 and 1 or x * fact_or(x-1)
print fact_or(10)
```

Comment: Yeah, this one is definitely more understandable. Clear "if/else" statements. But using "or" is much more succinct. Somehow, it's not very intuitive.

Comment: Using `i` or `l` for variable name are also succint, and sometimes I use them sometimes in hurry or out of old habbit. Often I also regret that afterwards.